# Get an argument error in ruby blocks

Tags: ruby, block, yield

```
module Framework
 class CreateTableDefinition 
   attr_accessor :host, :username, :password
 end 
end

def create_table(table_name)
  obj = Framework::CreateTableDefinition.new
  yield(obj) if block_given?
end

create_table :users do |config|
  config.host :localhost
end
```

And here is the error I get

```
-:13:in `block in <main>': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
    from -:9:in `create_table'
    from -:12:in `<main>'
```

If I change  the code to

```
config.host = :localhost
```

it works fine. But what I want is to work as described above config.host :localhost

Comment: It sounds like you want the `CreateTableDefinition` class to have a `host` method that assigns its argument to the `@host` local, does that sound right?

Comment: @AndrewPiliser, correct but I want to ommit the = I spot that most of the RoR code make the assignments like that config.host :localhost. See no =

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed assignment:

```
config.host = :localhost
```

## Edit

If you want to get rid of assignments, you need to define setter methods without `=` at the end. This might generate quote a lot of code, so I would rather go with some meta-programming (because it's fun!)

```
class MyConfigClass
  def self.attributes(*args)
    args.each do |attr|
      define_method attr do |value|
        @attributes[attr] = value
      end
    end
  end

  def initialize
    @attributes = {}
  end

  def get(attr)
     @attributes[attr]
  end 
end

class CreateTableDefinition < MyConfigClass
   attributes :host, :username, :password
end

c = CreateTableDefinition.new
c.host :localhost
c.get(:host)   #=> :localhost
```

Comment: I know that but how to do to work with config.host :localhost?
I'm learning ruby and notice that most of the RoR blocks make the assignment in that way

Comment: @MZON - I wouldn't say most, rails config uses standard assignments. I'll update the question with how to do that in a second.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually making a method that does what you want instead of using the `attr_accessor` shortcut.

```
class CreateTableDefinition 
  attr_accessor :username, :password

  def host(sym)
    @host = sym
  end

  def get_host
    @host
  end
end
```

If you don't like the idea of writing those methods for every attribute, look into writing your own helper, something like `attr_rails_like`, and mix it in to the `Class` object. [This](http://mikeyhogarth.wordpress.com/2011/12/01/creating-your-own-attr_accessor-in-ruby/) article might be helpful.